# Match a pattern preceded by a specific pattern without using a lookbehind

Tags: regex, eclipse, regex-lookarounds

Is there a way to match a `B` only if preceded by an `A`?  The `A` can be at any position behind the `B`, with any amount of characters between.  Examples:

```
A_B (Matches `B`)

C_B (No match)
```

I've tried:

```
(?=A)[^B]*B
```

But it matches all the characters preceeding `B` as well.  My regex engine does not support variable length look-behinds.  Is there any way I can do this?

Edit: I am currently using the built in regex search in Eclipse, however, I am using regex101.com to test things out.

Comment: Are you using this expression from a Java program?

Comment: You also didn't specify the regex language, which may get you lots of answers you don't want.

Comment: @anubhava I only want the `B` to match.  Question was edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A work-around for the lack of variable-length lookbehind is available in situations when your strings have a relatively small fixed upper limit on their length. For example, if you know that strings are at most 100 characters long, you could use `{0,100}` in place of `*` or `{1,100}` in place of `+` inside the lookbehind expression:

```
(?<=A[^B]{0,100})B
```

When the length of your string has no obvious upper limit, you could drop lookbehind altogether, use a non-capturing group in its place, place a capturing group over `B`, and use the content of that group as the result of your regular expression.

Comment: Now that I think about it more, I think the non-capture/capture group solution the correct one.  What I essentially want to do is keep the match position in the string *after* the lookahead succeeds, but it doesn't work like that.  And that fixed length repition quantifier fo the lookbehind is cool.  Didn't know about that.  Thanks for the answer.